# C# WinForms, what is this strange error?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-3.5

I am new to C# WinForms. I have made a class (EnhancedForm) which inherits Form class. In EnhanceForm I have put some common functions (like validations, common used objects like DataTable and string variables etc, so that I may not have to code same again and again in forms) that I want to use in all forms and next all of my forms inherits this (EnhancedForm).

In DAL (a separate class library) I have a class CommonDB class which have DB related common functions. For database communications I was making an object of CommonDB in all forms. I thought to put CommonDB in EnhancedForm so that I may not have to make its objects in all classes.

Here is something happening that I couldn't understand. Application runs fine. But if I try to open a form in design view it gives an error. **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object. "** I couldn't view a form in designed mode. If I remove CommonDb object from EnhancedForm and put it in individual forms it works fine and allow to view forms.

If I compile and run this error do not appears. Please guide and help me in this regard.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have code in EnhancedForm that assumes a CommonDb object. At runtime you create that (probably in Form_Loaded) but Design-time it is absent.

Preferrably, all your code accessing CommonDb should check for null, and/or this.DesignMode

Comment: I don't know about recent versions of VS/.NET (we are still on 2005 at work), but the DesignMode property used to, well, not work at all.  Hopefully they have fixed it.

Comment: Thanks Henk for guiding, but a strange thing is this happen with all forms. Suppose I used CommonDB object in form1 but design view of all forms gone by this.  2nd thing is that in EnhancedForm I have done a funtion to close the form if user press escape key. If I start using Commondb this funtion stop its working. I am not getting where I am wrong.

Comment: Even on form load I re-instantiate Commondb but issue still remains. Before calling it even I put if not equal to null but results are same. Plz advice.

Comment: We won't be able to help unless you show how/where you create the CommonDb, how you use it etc. List all constructors. The Esc key is a separate question. Again, provide code.

Comment: @hansi, debug your InitializeLayout method, can't you?

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if you are initiating your CommonDB class inside your base form's constructor. Visual Studio uses Reflection to show forms in design view, that causes the form's constructor to be called. You could try just rebuilding the project to see if you can see the forms in design view but I do not think it will work.